# Como arredondar valor sem centavos para baixo?

Tags: php, matemática

Como arredondar valores que não tenha centavos e só tenha números?

Ex: 10, 20, 30, 40, 50. Se pessoa tiver 13, ficar 10, se tiver 25 fica 20.

Comment: O que voce já fez?

Comment: é pra arredondar sempre para baixo?

Comment: @FleuquerLima sim, o bigown já me ajudou. Obrigado todos vocês.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Divida por 10 e use a função [`intval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) para pegar a parte inteira, ele perderá a parte "quebrada", aí multiplique por 10 de novo para restabelecer a magnitude.

Se precisar arredondar pra cima normalmente somaria mais 5 ou outro número, depende da intenção. Mas isto pode variar.

Se precisar arredondar duas casas, a grandeza deve ser 100 e não 10.

Pode-se criar uma função para generalizar isto.

```
echo intval(13 / 10) * 10 . "\n";
echo intval(25 / 10) * 10 . "\n";
echo intval(137 / 10) * 10 . "\n";
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/IDefTG). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/mezqvssb-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Math/RoundDown.php).

Também existe a função pronta [`round()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) que faz isto. O parâmetro de casas decimais pode ser negativo, isso significa que as casas são à esquerda da vírgula, como quer. Mas ela não garante que arredondará pra baixo.

Comment: deu certo, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Uma variação da resposta aceita, compatível apenas com o *PHP* versão maior ou igual a 7, seria fazer a divisão inteira do número por dez e multiplicar o resultado por 10 utilizando a função [`intdiv()`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.intdiv.php) que retorna o quociente inteiro da divisão.

```
echo intdiv(13, 10) * 10 . "\n";    //10
echo intdiv(25, 10) * 10 . "\n";    //20
echo intdiv(137, 10) * 10 . "\n";   //130
```

<sup>Teste o código no [IDEOne](https://ideone.com/AEWfJa)</sup>